# PHP reuse SSH connection in another page

Tags: php, ssh

Just wondering, is there anyway to reuse a ssh connection in abother php script page.
like, I open a connection on page A, and I finished ahtorization, but I want to process user command in another script page B, is ther any way to run the command avoid to estanblish another connection?

Answer (score 2):

@code_burgar: what about mysql_pconnect()?

To the OP: what about replacing all instances of fsockopen() with pfsockopen() in [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpseclib/)

Answer (score 1):

Won't work for the same reasons that a MySQL connection opened in one php script wont work in a second one.

Answer (score 1):

No, php closes all the resource handles when it's finished. Even if it didn't, you can't save the state of a resource.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done if you use OpenSSH to connect to the remote server and use the connection multiplexing feature.

Read the [ssh manual pages](http://openssh.com/manual.html) for the details, specially the ControlMaster entry in [ssh_config(5)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5).